# Getting list of cities connected directly woth a city by road

Tags: google-maps, distance

Is there some way to get list of cities connected directly with a city using google maps api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do that with the Google Maps API. You would have to know which cities you're interested in before hand and use the Distance Matrix.